# Is it possible to change pixels matrix inside of Bitmap in android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I wanna replace pixels for bitmap without creating a new one instance of bitmap. Is it possible to change void * pixels for bitmap which was given to native method without creating a new one instance of bitmap?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Android NDK r8b documentation ("Stable APIs" section), you can pass a Bitmap to the NDK layer and process its pixels from there:

> The 'jnigraphics' Library:
>
> This is a tiny library that exposes a stable, C-based, interface that
>   allows native code to reliably access the pixel buffers of Java bitmap
>   objects.
>
> To use it, include the  header in your source code,
>   and and link to the jnigraphics library as in:
>
> LOCAL_LDLIBS += -ljnigraphics
>
> For details, read the source header at the following location:
>
> ```
> build/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/android/bitmap.h
> ```
>
> Briefly, typical usage should look like:
>
> ```
> 1/ Use AndroidBitmap_getInfo() to retrieve information about a
>    given bitmap handle from JNI (e.g. its width/height/pixel format)
>
> 2/ Use AndroidBitmap_lockPixels() to lock the pixel buffer and
>    retrieve a pointer to it. This ensures the pixels will not move
>    until AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels() is called.
>
> 3/ Modify the pixel buffer, according to its pixel format, width,
>    stride, etc.., in native code.
>
> 4/ Call AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels() to unlock the buffer.
> ```

Comment: I know that. Is it possible to change WxH to HxW in NDK or not?

Comment: Not as far as I know. If you look at the `bitmap.h` header file suggested above, it says that AndroidBitmap_getInfo() *fills* the AndroidBitmapInfo C structure containing the width and height of the bitmap from the Java object, but nothing mentions the possibility to backport these values into the Java object: "Given a java bitmap object, fill out the AndroidBitmap struct for it."

The above documentation also says that you can "Modify the pixel buffer, *according to its pixels format, width, stride, etc...*", which also implies that these values are constants that you can't modify.

Comment: To sum it up, these methods are here just to help "re-painting" a bitmap. For deeper modifications such as changing dimensions, I fear you'll have to create a new Bitmap...

Comment: Okay. If I create a new one bitmap in NDK, will I replace data of got bitmap for data from a new bitmap?